# visualVM heap analysis can this be a issue

Tags: java, garbage-collection, heap-memory

does this make sense or it means that there are minor or major gc happening which is a concern for a low latency app

[image: VisualVM Heap]

I agree that there are gc happening, and thats why graph goes down, but can this happen because of bad design.
Or its all subjective ?

Comment: Are you referring to the sawtooth-like part of the graph (if so, this is not uncommon) or the rapid-changing central part of the graph?

Comment: anything in the above graph looks phisy

Answer (score 0):

Allocation and Deallocation  pattern occurs based on the GC policy.

For example if the gc policy is meant for throughput then application allocate object continiously till it reaches Xmx  when
JVM find no further allocation can be done then GC kicks for deallocation. If Gc policy meant for low pause time then 
2 types of GC occurs one is scavenge gc occurs at young area and another Gc when java heap allocation reaches the -Xmx level.
Excessive GC  calls leads to performance  degradation of the application. Check with the GC policy,Heap Size and allocation/deallocation 
pattern based on that we could say above graph pattern is acceptable or not.